# How can I tell the difference between the JID of a user and a JID of MUC?

Tags: xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

Suppose I have two JIDs:

- JID 1: `bob@example.com`
- JID 2  `room@chat.example.com`

JID 2 clearly refers to the chat server, but the chat server isn't always going to have the word chat or conference in it.

Is there a way, using the Smack libraries, to tell which one is which?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell by looking at the JID.  You have to keep enough context in a given protocol exchange to know what you are talking to.

Typically on startup, a client will send a [`disco#items`](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#items) query to the server:

```xml
<iq type='get'
    to='shakespeare.lit'
    id='items1'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

to find all of the local services, then send a [`disco#info`](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info) query to each of those services to find out more about the service.  Once you [find a MUC server](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-service):

```xml
<iq from='chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'>
    <identity
        category='conference'
        name='Shakespearean Chat Service'
        type='text'/>
    <feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
  </query>
</iq>
```

you know that all of the JIDs that include this domain name (`chat.shakespeare.lit` in the above example) are associated with MUC rooms.

Comment: Is there any way I can tell by sending a certain IQ stanza at looking at the response?

Answer (score 0):

A user JID in a MUC will (should) have the username at the end and will look like:

```
roomname@conference.example.com/username
```

Comment: That will be the user's nickname in the room, which might be different from their username.